# application specific fonts settings in Linux Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: fonts

system -> appearance gives the fonts dialogue which I use to set fonts for the entire gnome session. Is there a way I can setup fonts for a specific application.

I have imported fonts from the windows 7 fonts folder and applied Segoe UI to all the applications. chrome is my browser of preference and the fonts in the address bar are jumping when I type.

I changed it to other font - verdana and its working fine in chrome. But its set for all the application.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can set application specific fonts in the Gnome menu. You may have to resort to the application settings themselves and see if they provide a way to change fonts.